Fill graph doesn't work for line charts in chart.js 3.9.1 version
I'm plotting a line chart in my react project using chart.js (3.9.1). This is the data I'm passing to the chart. I can see the chart but I don't see the fill color for the chart. Strangely I see the same borderColor and backgroundColor for the legend instead of the chart.Fill color applied for the legend instead of the chart
{
    "labels": [
        "2024-08-18",
        "2024-08-19"
    ],
    "datasets": [
        {
            "label": "Custom",
            "data": [
                4.62,
                4
            ],
            "tension": 0.6,
            // "fill": true,
            "fill": "origin",
            "borderColor": "#1C5789",
            "borderWidth": 4,
            "pointRadius": 0,
            "pointHoverRadius": 6,
            "pointHoverBackgroundColor": "white",
            "backgroundColor": "black"
        }
    ]
}

These are the options I passed to the chart.
{
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    interaction: {
      mode: "index",
      intersect: false,
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: "top",
        labels: {
          usePointStyle: true,
          color: theme === "dark" ? "white" : "black",
          font: {
            size: 12,
            color: theme === "dark" ? "white" : "black",
          },
          pointStyle: "circle",
          pointStyleWidth: 16,
          padding: 20,
          boxWidth: 12,
        },
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
        external: (context) => {
          // Tooltip Element
          var tooltipEl = document.getElementById("chartjs-tooltip");

          // Create element on first render
          if (!tooltipEl) {
            tooltipEl = document.createElement("div");
            tooltipEl.id = "chartjs-tooltip";
            tooltipEl.innerHTML = "<div></div>";
            document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
          }

          // Hide if no tooltip
          const tooltipModel = context.tooltip;
          if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0) {
            if (tooltipEl) {
              tooltipEl.remove();
            }
            return;
          }
          // Set caret Position
          tooltipEl.classList.remove("above", "below", "no-transform");
          if (tooltipModel.yAlign) {
            tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltipModel.yAlign);
          } else {
            tooltipEl.classList.add("no-transform");
          }

          function getBody(bodyItem) {
            return bodyItem.lines;
          }

          // Set Text
          if (tooltipModel.body) {
            let innerHtml = "<div class=" + styles.driversTooltip + ">";
            tooltipModel.dataPoints.forEach((dataPoint) => {
              const dataset = dataPoint.dataset;
              const datasetLabel = dataPoint.label;
              const datasetValue = dataPoint.raw;
              innerHtml += `
                <div class=${styles.topicLabelInTooltip}>
                  <span class=${styles.fillColor} style="background-color: ${dataset?.borderColor}"></span>
                  <span class=${styles.topicLabel}>${datasetLabel}: ${datasetValue}</span>
                </div>`;
            });
            innerHtml += "</div>";
            const tooltipRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector("div");
            tooltipRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
          }
          // this will be the overall tooltip
          const position = context.chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

          // Display, position, and set styles for font
          tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
          tooltipEl.style.position = "absolute";
          let left = position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltipModel.caretX;
          if (left + tooltipEl.offsetWidth > window.innerWidth) {
            left =
              position.left +
              window.pageXOffset / 2 +
              tooltipModel.caretX -
              tooltipEl.offsetWidth;
          }
          tooltipEl.style.left = left + "px";
          tooltipEl.style.top =
            position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltipModel.caretY + "px";
          tooltipEl.style.padding =
            tooltipModel.padding + "px " + tooltipModel.padding + "px";
          tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        },
      },
      datalabels: {
        display: false,
      },
      filler: {
        propagate: true,
      },
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          borderColor:
            theme === "dark"
              ? "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)"
              : "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)",
          color: "#808080",
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          drawTicks: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          padding: 20,
          color: theme === "dark" ? "white" : "black",
        },
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        ticks: {
          padding: 20,
          color: theme === "dark" ? "white" : "black",
        },
        grid: {
          borderColor:
            theme === "dark"
              ? "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)"
              : "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)",
          color: theme === "dark" ? "white" : "black",
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          drawTicks: false,
        },
        afterDataLimits: (axis) => {
          const max = axis.max;
          let addVal = 0;
          if (max < 5) {
            addVal = 1;
          } else if (max < 10) {
            addVal = 3;
          } else if (max < 100) {
            addVal = 10;
          } else if (max < 1000) {
            addVal = 50;
          } else if (max < 10000) {
            addVal = 500;
          } else if (max < 100000) {
            addVal = 1000;
          } else if (max < 1000000) {
            addVal = 5000;
          } else {
            addVal = 10000;
          }
          axis.max += addVal;
        },
      },
    },
 }

I checked the chart.js documentation and tried the same options and datasets in the config example chart. Chart.js documentation It fills the chart. I tried every method like fill: true, fill: "origin", fill: "1", "fill": 1, in the datasets but nothing is working.
Chart.js documentation example

Your options and data do result in a black fill, see jsFiddle. Since you're using modules in React, have you imported the Filler plugin? See this post about that.
